# Understanding interface casting

Tags: c#

Why is it that I can cast a Component class instance to an interface like:

```
public Component FindComponent<T>()
{
    var comp = (from c in components
                where typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(c.GetType())
                select c).FirstOrDefault();

    return comp;
}

foreach(var a in actors)
{
    IHealth health = a.FindComponent<IHealth>() as IHealth;
}
```

But I can't cast it inside the `FindComponent()` if I do:

```
public T FindComponent<T>()
{
    var comp = (from c in components
                where typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(c.GetType())
                select c).FirstOrDefault();

    return comp as T;
}
```

As this gives the error: The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint.

It's just easier for the user to not have to cast after the `FindComponent()`. Unity 3D has a similar function and you don't have to cast after it comes back and I'm not sure how it does the cast inside `FindComponent()` but I'm trying to replicate that.

Comment: add `where T : class` to the function: `public T FindComponent<T>() where T : class`

Comment: Didn't change anything. Same error.

Comment: Side note: you can simplify your first linq query by doing this: `var comp = components.FirstOrDefault(c => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(c.GetType())`

Comment: @AleksAndreev I prefer the sql like syntax personally.

Comment: @user441521, `where T : class` will remove compiler error you mentioned. (as error message stays itself _because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint_.

Comment: Yes, but now it's erroring out saying it cannot convert type 'Component' to 'T'. So Health is a class that derives from Component and implements IHealth. The idea is querying the components list, which I added a Health object to, to find a component that implements IHealth. It finds the Health object correctly, but I'd want to only return the IHealth component so I can only interact with the interface methods.

Comment: Your method can simply look like: `return components.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Yes, what Fabio mentioned is better - the casting occurs in "OfType" and you don't have to worry about it.  Then you just return the first object from that function.

Comment: That works Fabio thanks! Strange the description in the editor of that function doesn't mention that it casts to that type.

Comment: @Fabio `OfType` is for sequences that may not be of the proper type.  `Cast` is for casting objects you know are of another type.

Comment: @Servy, as OP said in the comments _to find a component that implements IHealth_ - I think it's fit to the _sequences that may not be of the proper type(IHealth in OP case)_

Answer (score 0):

The 'as' keyword will give you a null value if the cast fails.  But in this case, what you need to do is an implicit cast, because you've already checked that this is possible.

```
return (T) comp;
```

Comment: This gives me the error: Cannot convert type 'Component' to 'T'. Cast is redudant but if I remove the cast I get error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'Component' to 'T'.

Comment: Ok.  Does the "components" queryable/list/whatever implement an OfType<> method?